# Estimating Returns with the Non-Central t-distribution

Tags: programming, returns, simulations, asset-returns

The Boost C++ Libraries provide a set of statistical distributions in their Math Toolkit library.  The best candidate I can find among those available that will capture skew and kurtosis typically present in financial returns is the [non-central t-distribution](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_81_0/libs/math/doc/html/math_toolkit/dist_ref/dists/nc_t_dist.html).  The input parameters are the degrees of freedom and a skewness parameter.

If I wanted to use this to model financial returns, however, I would also need to adjust for location and scale.  This can be done fairly easily for the regular (symmetric) t-distribution.  Supposing I had a random sample from a t-distribution, say $\{x_i\}$, and I had estimates for the degrees of freedom, location (mean in this case), and scale values, $m$ and $s$.  Then, I could get a set of simulated returns $\{y_i\}$ by applying the location-scale transformation

$$y_i  = s x_i + m$$

My (perhaps naïve) questions are:

1. Would the above transformation for the symmetric case be reasonably close to the non-central case if the skew is "reasonably small"?
2. Alternatively, could the same linear form be used, but perhaps with a more robust estimate for $s$ in the case of the non-central t-distribution (presumably using the mean for $m$ would still be appropriate given the shifted standard normal random variable in the pdf for the non-central t-distribution)?  If so, what would be this preferred estimate?  Could it be derived from the data *similar to* $s$ in the case of the symmetric t-distribution, ie similar to

$$s = \sqrt{\frac{\nu - 2}{\nu}}$$  where $\nu$ = the degrees of freedom, and $\sigma$ is the standard deviation in the symmetric case?

3. Or, finally, would we need to scrap the linear form above and use an alternative?  If so, what might it be?

I have checked a number of research papers and other resources on the internet, but while there is ample information on the distribution itself and other applications, answers to the above have proven elusive so far.